# Writing data frame to semicolon-delimited CSV where column data contains semi-colon?

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, separator, quoting

How do I write to a CSV with the following data intact? I want to write this data to a CSV file with separator as semicolon but the 2nd row is getting shifted because of the semicolon.

I have a data frame with the following data:

```
             a <- c(1,2,3,4)
             b <- c("hello","hello;world","hey","there")
             c <- c(10,20,30,40)
             df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
             df
             df
               a           b  c
             1 1       hello 10
             2 2 hello;world 20
             3 3         hey 30
             4 4       there 40
```

Comment: ("CSV file" generically refers to any separator-delimited text file, and it is legitimate for fields to contain that separator, that's what quoting is for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the output:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
b<-c("hello","hello;world","hey","there")
c<-c(10,20,30,40)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c)
write.table(df, file="blah.csv",quote=TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Gives

```
"a";"b";"c"
"1";1;"hello";10
"2";2;"hello;world";20
"3";3;"hey";30
"4";4;"there";40
```

Comment: Note to OP: `quote=TRUE` is the default for `write.table`, so you don't have to specify it every time you use `write.table`.

Comment: I had a query. By adding quote="TRUE", the column names will also be quoted. Can this be prevented in any way? I just want the above behavior with unquoted column names.